# C++ operator << (void*)

Tags: c++, serialization, operators, iostream

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class oTraceStream : public std::ostringstream
{
public :

    oTraceStream(const int from, const unsigned int level)
    : m_from(from)
    , m_level(level)
    {
    }

    virtual ~oTraceStream(void)
    {
        std::cout << str();
    }

private :
    // unused for this sample
    int m_from;
    unsigned int m_level;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    oTraceStream(0,0) << "1st part " << " 2nd part" << std::endl;
    {
        oTraceStream tmp(0,0);
        tmp << "1st part " << " 2nd part" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With MS Visual 6.0 or old gcc( 2.x), the 2 outputs were the same.

```
1st part  2nd part
1st part  2nd part
```

With MS Visual 2008 or recent gcc (4.x) the first string of the first line is displayed as a pointer

```
0x80493ec 2nd part
1st part  2nd part
```

Can someone explain me why, whith recent compiler the first line is displayed using ostream::operator<<(const void* p) instead of ostream::operator<<(const char *) ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore standard `std::ostringstream::str()`

Comment: Side note: Stream classes such as `ostringstream` should *not* be subclassed. Only `streambuf` should. (Well, you can make analogous subclasses as `ostringstream` corresponds to `stringbuf`.)

Comment: Note, that recent gcc versions output the second example of output unless using an older standard than C++11, [live using C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23972b7494d8cb63) and [live using C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbfc6dec419c6d23).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `void const *` overload is a member of `std::ostream`, whereas the `char const *` overload is a non-member. The temporary `oTraceStream(0,0)` object will not bind to the non-const reference used by non-member `operator <<`, but it will bind to the implicit `this` parameter used by the member.

C++11 causes behavior to go back to your expectation, as it adds an `operator <<` which takes an rvalue (e.g. a temporary object subexpression) and switches it to an lvalue (e.g. a named object subexpression).